# java apps freeze mac os 10.9

Tags: java, macos, freeze

I need help.
I have mac os 10.9 and installed java JDK 1.7.
java -version:

> java version "1.7.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

All java apps freezing. java control panel freezing too.
For example: I open java control panel. At start all ok, but after a few seconds when i press several tabs or buttons - java control panel freeze.

There are no same problem with mac os 10.8 and java 6.

p.s. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What java control panel? I'm happily running java apps on my 10.9 systems without issue.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you resolved this issue. But there might be a background application interacting badly. T

his is usually due to an app having access in the accessibility section.

So go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility > Disable everything. and then test your system. If it runs properly then enable one applications at a time, to figure out which ones are interacting badly with java. In my case the problem was Flexiglass.

Comment: It was BetterTouchTool for me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah! Found the solution to my own problem... it was TextExpander the one that was freezing Java when I tried to write anything. Disabling it whenever I need to use the Java app solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was RescueTime. Workaround does help

Answer (score 0):

For me it was KITE - a code autocomplete plugin which made java text entry fields impossible to use, hanging for minutes.